# extract strings before and after a keyword in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a .sca file (which can be read as a text file) from omnet. I need to extract some numbers after a certain parameter. For exmaple:

```
scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   "packets sent"  1041
scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   "packets received"  0
scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   sentPk:count    1041
attr interpolationmode  none
attr unit  bps
scalar SendIntBitRate.host2.udpApp[0]   rcvdPk:count    93
attr interpolationmode  none
attr source  rcvdPk
```

Now I need to read the keywords/number just before and after sentPk:count and rcvdPk:count (eg here  SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0] ,  1041) and write it into a csv file. Note that multiple lines contain the sentPk:count and rcvdPk:count keywords. I am storing the whole file in cell C as:

```
fid = fopen('1Mbps1000us1250B\BR1MBPS1MS-0.sca','r')
C = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fid)
C = C{:};
```

Which give me rows such as `scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   sentPk:count    1041`

But now in these row, how can I extract the text just before and after the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split by space and perform traditional search:

```
inp = 'scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   sentPk:count    1041';
s=regexp(inp, '\s+','split');

idx = find(strcmp(s, 'sentPk:count'));
if length(idx) == 1
   before = s{idx - 1};
   after = s{idx + 1};
end
```

Regexp-oneliner is also possible but I don't think that it is more clear:

```
a=regexp(inp, '(\S+)\s+sentPk:count\s+(\d+)', 'tokens')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick response. The one liner lemda function is perfect. As I am wrting it in a complete cell insted of a single inp, I need to remove the empty cells afterwords. Which I have done Like this : `fid = fopen('1Mbps1000us1250B\BR1MBPS1MS-0.sca','r')
C = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fid)
C = C{:};
a=regexp(C, '(\S+)\s+sentPk:count\s+(\d+)', 'tokens')
a_new = a(~cellfun(@isempty, a))`  and its working perfectly, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you already have each line in a string, say

```
str = 'scalar SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]   sentPk:count    1041';
```

it's easy to extract the parts (delimited spaces) before and after `'sentPk:count'` using a regular expression with [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
result_before = regexp(str, '\S+(?=\s+sentPk:count)', 'match');
result_before = result_before{1};
result_after = regexp(str, '(?<=sentPk:count\s+)\S+', 'match');
result_after = result_after{1};
```

In the example, this produces the strings

```
result_before =
SendIntBitRate.host1.udpApp[0]

result_after =
1041
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, for this explaination. Its really helpful and quite simple to understand. Thanks